# Rails validate uniqueness based on another field on the same table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a table of users, this table has two columns: `email` (unique, index) and `new_email` (index).

When the user needs to change his email, the `new_email` saves this new address until confirmation. I need to validate it against the `email` column so I don't get a uniqueness error when I try and confirm it, updating the `email` field.
I already tried scope, but it doesn't seem to work in my case.

As this is a legacy project, I can't change this flow/structure. So I'm looking for a "rails way" to do this validation.

Comment: [Custom validation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations) e.g. `validate :new_email_unique; def new_email_unique; errors.add(:new_email, 'already taken') if User.where(email: self.new_email).exists?; end`

Comment: @engineersmnky this actually solved my problem, thank you! Can you give it as an answer so I can accept it?